# When using a scala macro, why the compilation error stacktrace looks so incoherent?

Tags: scala, gradle, shapeless, scala-macros, scalac

I'd like to experiment scala on some unreliable macro. So I mimic a simple error in shapeless invocation:

```
import shapeless.Witness

    val v = Witness(Random.nextInt())
```

Then I compile it with `gradle build --info --stacktrace`, expecting to find an exception that starts with 'shapeless.Witness' or something similar. Instead I got this:

```
> Task :common:compileTestScala
[Error] /home/peng/git-spike/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/shapeless_spike/RefinedType/Creation.scala:12: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt() does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
one error found

> Task :common:compileTestScala FAILED
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:compileTestScala'.
> Compilation failed

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':common:compileTestScala'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompilerFacade.execute(ZincScalaCompilerFacade.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompilerFacade.execute(ZincScalaCompilerFacade.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.execute(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:84)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:129)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: Compilation failed
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:253)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:122)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
    at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)
    at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:147)
    ... 21 more
```

How is this supposed to help me? I can only see the code of `shapeless.Witness`, not the entire `sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler`. What should I do to see the error that can be related to the macro that actually reported the error?

**UPDATE 1** On behalf of Dmytro Mitin I'd like to also attach my build configurations:

```
allprojects {

    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "scala")

...

    dependencies {

        implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:${vs.scalaV}")
        implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:${vs.scalaV}")
        implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:${vs.scalaV}")
<vs.scalaV=2.12.11>
... 
<witness is introduced in s submodule>
    }

    tasks {

        val jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()

        withType<ScalaCompile> {

            targetCompatibility = jvmTarget

            scalaCompileOptions.loggingLevel = "debug"

            scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = listOf(
                    "-encoding", "utf8",
                    "-unchecked",
                    "-deprecation",
                    "-feature",
                    "-Xfatal-warnings",
                    "-Xlog-implicits",
                    "-Yissue-debug"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** on maven:

```
[ERROR] /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/core/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/utils/WitnessSpike.scala:11: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt() does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
[ERROR]   Witness(Random.nextInt())
[ERROR]          ^

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.6:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spookystuff-core: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.6:testCompile failed.: CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.6:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spookystuff-core: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.6:testCompile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.6:testCompile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sbt.compiler.CompileFailed
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call (AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile (AnalyzingCompiler.scala:53)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile (AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp (AggressiveCompile.scala:95)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply (AggressiveCompile.scala:95)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply (AggressiveCompile.scala:95)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed (AggressiveCompile.scala:168)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1 (AggressiveCompile.scala:94)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply (AggressiveCompile.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply (AggressiveCompile.scala:84)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply (Compile.scala:66)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply (Compile.scala:64)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle (IncrementalCommon.scala:32)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply (Incremental.scala:72)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply (Incremental.scala:71)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles (Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile (Incremental.scala:71)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply (Compile.scala:54)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2 (AggressiveCompile.scala:159)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1 (AggressiveCompile.scala:68)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile (Compiler.scala:207)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile (Compiler.scala:189)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile (Compiler.scala:180)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile (Compiler.scala:171)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile (SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:94)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:320)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:136)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:116)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute (ScalaMojoSupport.java:574)
    at scala_maven.ScalaTestCompileMojo.execute (ScalaTestCompileMojo.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Oops, equally useless. Can't believe I had high hope for it. Relevenat build plugin configuration looks like this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
        <executions>

          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!--required for publishing to maven central-->
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>doc-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
<!--                see https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4000-->
                <arg>-nobootcp</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <scalaCompatVersion>${scala.binary.version}</scalaCompatVersion>
          <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
          <!--https://tpolecat.github.io/2017/04/25/scalac-flags.html-->
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-${java.version}</arg>
            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
            <arg>-feature</arg>
            <arg>-g:vars</arg>

            <arg>-encoding</arg>
            <arg>UTF-8</arg>

            <arg>-Xlint</arg>
          </args>
          <javacArgs>
            <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
            <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
            <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
            <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
          </javacArgs>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/.ipynb_checkpoints/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

**UPDATE 3** I finally tried on sbt, but apparently the macro stacktrace option cannot be enabled. This is the scalac configuration in sbt build file:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  //                            "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Xlint:poly-implicit-overload",
  "-Xlint:option-implicit",
//  "-Xlog-implicits",
//  "-Xlog-implicit-conversions",
  "-Yissue-debug"
)
scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) ++= Seq("-groups")

/** Enable for debugging */
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oF")
```

Then it shows even less information than maven & gradle:

```
> run
[warn] Credentials file /home/peng/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /home/peng/.ivy2/.sbtcredentials does not exist
[info] Compiling 235 Scala sources and 30 Java sources to /home/peng/git-release/spark-nlp/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/peng/git-release/spark-nlp/src/main/scala/com/johnsnowlabs/collections/SearchTrie.scala:86: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt() does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
[error]   Witness(Random.nextInt())
[error]          ^
[warn] /home/peng/git-release/spark-nlp/src/main/scala/com/johnsnowlabs/ml/tensorflow/TensorflowSpell.scala:134: inferred existential type (org.tensorflow.Tensor[?0], org.tensorflow.Tensor[?0], org.tensorflow.Tensor[?0]) forSome { type ?0; type ?0; type ?0 }, which cannot be expressed by wildcards,  should be enabled
... (skipping irrelevant warnings)
[warn] 9 warnings found
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed 28-Jul-2020 12:44:30 AM
> 
> 
> 
> last run
> 
>
```

Do I miss something in any of these build system?

Comment: Obviously this is some gradle issue (issue with how you run compilation of your code, does gradle launch sbt?) since with sbt or just scalac compile error is "Expression `scala.util.Random.nextInt()` does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value" https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rHSBWDpXSlyN0ezKui3G4w If you use some build tool you should know how to set it up properly.

Comment: I'm well aware of the shapeless error (I've read the source code) and the fact that gradle is piggybacking on sbt. This is just a simple example to show the problem. I've encountered very complex macro errors in singleton-ops and there is no way I can figure out.

Comment: I'm kind of curious of what build tool are you using? People rarely use scalac directly, it would be either maven, mill, sbt or gradle (which is technically also sbt), I haven't try mill but I'll post the stacktrace on maven shortly. I doubt if it is any better

Comment: As I wrote in my comment I tried sbt (`sbt compile`, default build tool) and just in case scalac (`scalac -classpath ~/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.13/bundles/shapeless_2.13-2.4.0-M1.jar src/main/scala/App.scala`). I'm just curious what's the reason to run compilation with gradle launching sbt while you can run sbt directly. Try to clean project before compilation.

Comment: And I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect publishing exception and not publishing even build file, versions used etc.

Comment: I see, will publish relevant part in scala gradle/maven/sbt plugins

Comment: Can you use sbt rather than maven or gradle?

Comment: By the way, you can report about bugs/feature requests in Maven and Gradle Scala plugins here: https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues and  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues?q=scala

Comment: I've seen https://github.com/tribbloid/shapesafe Probably you use gradle for cross-building Scala and Kotlin. For sbt there is plugin for building Kotlin https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin

Comment: just ran on sbt, but instead of showing the wrong stacktrace it is not showing any. Would you mind sharing with me your project and the sbt command you have used?

Comment: Ok, I'll do. Meanwhile you can look at https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html

Comment: Sorry for late response. Did you manage to work with sbt or do you still need a sample project?

Comment: I guess you didn't switch on `"-Ymacro-debug-lite"` scalac option.

Answer (score 2):

Do other compiler errors give you useful stacktraces?

Stack traces are fundamentally a runtime thing: the only stacktrace you can have at compile time is the stacktrace within the compiler (e.g. the `sbt.compiler` package in the stack traces in the question).

In general, to debug macro issues, depending on the issue, you'll either:

- Run the Scala compiler inside a debugger (there are [instructions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)) if the macro in question is failing to expand
- Dumping the generated code with the `-Ymacro-debug-lite` compiler option, which will give you the generated Scala code and the abstract syntax tree representation; this would be useful only in the case where the macro expands but either itself fails to compile or exhibits a runtime bug